# accessing R from SAS

Tags: r, sas

I have both SAS (9.3) and R (2.14.0) installed on the same PC and I'd like to submit R statements within SAS using `submit / R;` and `endsubmit;`.

However:

```
SAS option RLANG is valid only at startup of the SAS System. The SAS option is
ignored.
```

Can you explain me how to circumvent this obstacle ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Put the following at the top of your SASV9.CFG file:

```
-RLANG
```

Answer (score 3):

To avoid having this option removed when Hot Fixes or updates are applied, the line can be added to sasv9_local.cfg.